# How can I recover the Chrome history which is deleted by CCleaner?

Tags: google-chrome, history, ccleaner

Yesterday, I updated CCleaner and did the "Easy Clean", then my Google Chrome history was deleted. I always uncheck the checkbox of deleting Chrome history because I want to keep it, but I didn't know the "Easy Clean" delete Chrome history automatically. Is there any way to recover my Chrome history?

Comment: In short, not possible. Because it was deleted yesterday and files are constantly overwritten in Chrome user folder.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method: restore it from your backup.

Less certainty: by using the file recovery software of your choice.

Comment: Your backup of what? Chrome? CCleaner? or Windows?

Comment: @Sickest - that's rather a dozy question, of which I presume you are already aware. Don't jibe, ask for clarification should you need it, or stay quiet if not.

Comment: No offense but it's not a dozy question, I've been doing this for a long time, and I have no idea what your talking about. Your answer isn't exactly high quality here. As far as i know, this is close to impossible to recover that kind of data. So what exactly are you backing up Tetsujin? Are you talking about a system restore? Or a backup of Chrome (Can you backup chrome? News to me) I want to know to learn just like the thousands of other people that are going to look at this question.

Comment: OK, forgive me assuming intent - it's hard to tell in text :  (cont'd...)

Comment: In this building, I back up every changed file on all computers once an hour; that goes back maybe a day, then daily for a week & weekly further than that on a rolling scheme. With that modulating granularity I can go back to approx last July for any changed or deleted file.I also make periodic clones, usually before major updates, so I have an 'instant fallback' in case something goes wrong. I also back up once a day, overnight, to an off-site location. Belt & braces in case the building burns down. If you want more detail, maybe post a question on backup strategies & how to plan.

Comment: You're talking about taking an image of the entire drive? And storing it on another server or off-site?

Comment: The off-site backups are not images, they are just file backups & don't include the OS. Images are too big. The local backups are either direct clones of the entire boot partition [in effect an image but actually bootable as they stand], which can be restored in half an hour to any empty drive, or the more comprehensive rolling scheme, which is fastest for doing such as the OP wants - to quickly restore an accidental erasure.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what program allows you to do this? I'm assuming its automated. Correct?

Comment: I use Acronis for the PCs, Time Machine for the Macs. Off-site is Backblaze. Clones are done with either Paragon Hard Disk Manager or Carbon Copy Cloner.

Answer (score 0):

The premise of recovery is that the deleted history is not overwritten, otherwise you will not be able to recover the overwritten history no matter what method you use. If you know this and can make sure it's not overwritten, then you can try to [recover the deleted Chrome history](https://www.fonecope.com/restore-chrome-history.html). The easiest and most suitable for all kinds of devices is to recover from My Activity, in addition to system restore. This is the step:
Sign in to Google Accounts > Launch Chrome and open google.com > Enter "My Activity" > Go to myactivity.google.com > Account Login > Now you can view deleted history on Chrome > select the link you want to recover and Open it > Save.
In addition, I have not heard of any way to back up Chrome history, which sounds incredible.